# Can I get some help understanding the exact definition of an Idol, and Worshiping an Idol?

Tags: idolatry

My definition of and Idol is hyper sensitive. Because at the moment I see it as a thing. Like this laptop for example. I have a great fear of Worshiping Idols. Like for example I am under the understanding that if I say "This is a great laptop" then I have just worshiped my idol. Not that I think that the laptop has anything to do with my creation or that God is in any way my laptop.

**I come to this conclusion because:**
“You shall not make for yourself a carved image or any likeness of anything that is in heaven above or that is on the earth beneath or that is in the water below. You shall not bow down to them or serve them, for I, the Lord, your God, am a jealous God... (Exodus 20:4-5)

Do not love the world or anything in the world. If anyone loves the world, love for the Father is not in them. (1 John 2:15)

Put to death, therefore, whatever belongs to your earthly nature: sexual immorality, impurity, lust, evil desires and greed, which is idolatry. (Col 3:5)

For you can be confident of this one thing: that no person who is immoral, impure, or greedy (such a person is an idolater) has any inheritance in the kingdom of Christ and God. (Ephesians 5:5)

It is for this reason that a woman ought to have power of choice over her self, because of the angels. (1 Corinthians 11:10)

**Why I need the Help:**
My understanding has made it very difficult to shop with my wife. I feel a guilt if I choose for her what to get. Or if I point out the advantages of one product over another I feel somehow that I am raising it (not to the level of God).

I have a lot of experience with the same forms of questions. Like the time we where picking out yarn. Truthfully I don't care what colors of yarn my wife picks out. I just trust that it will turn out fine. But a question will come like "Autumn needs a new scarf, and I don't know what colors to get her. What do you think?" I feel that if I make any choice at all then I'm wrong and stupid for the selection that I picked. Like "Oh those colors are horrible." Doesn't the very nature that my being wrong or feeling wrong in what I have done a version of sin. And then I'm receiving judgment, and I feel that I'm not in the spirit.

Seriously, I just need to really understand the correct perspective that God has on Idols. And If my saying "That looks like a cool shirt" is not idolatry, I need biblical proof that it is not, because it needs to come from Gods word, and not from Man. Because I don't want to worship Idols, and I don't want to become an Idol worshiper because some guy told me that wasn't what he was talking about.

Also bending over servicing Idols. I feel affected if I have to fix something under the sink, because I had to bend over. I fight the stress with faith in Jesus. Still I want to know, and Gods word says that if it something that he wants for me to understand. That his word will show me. So the answer has to be in their.

Comment: Welcome to the Christianity Stacks Exchange! I think your question may be inappropriate for this website. I highly recommend that you seek your pastoral counselor; that's what they're for. In the meantime, since you have more than 20 points, I suppose you can head to the Chatroom and type in a prayer request. :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why isn't the cross considered an idol?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/5412/why-isnt-the-cross-considered-an-idol)

Comment: There's not doctrinal frame here, there's no clear picture of what a correct answer looks like, it's dangerously close to asking for personal/pastoral advice. And, ultimately, you've rambled here for several paragraphs with none of it really aiding the reader in determining what you're getting at here. Could you cut out a bunch of the context, add a doctrinal frame and clarify what you're actually wanting to learn?

Comment: This question suggests a possible manifestation of obsessive-compulsive disorder. I would highly recommend speaking with a trusted religious leader and/or a mental health professional

Comment: @Daniel When you learn the meaning of Elohim you will want to know this as well. It is like peaking under a veil and going oh, I have been really doing it all wrong. And what "trusted religious leader" knows the real meaning to the word Elohim? And why should I subject myself to magic usage (what I consider using pharmaceuticals for mood stabilization)?

Answer (score 3):

Your question has many parts, and its obvious you take the matter seriously.

Highly esteeming objects in general is not idolatry:

[Luke 15:9](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Luke%2015:8-10;&version=NIV) - Woman and Drachma coin.

[Matthew 13:45-46](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew%2013:45-46%5C%27&version=AMP) - Merchant and pearl.

Objects seemingly valuable from man's standpoint can be used for good things:

[Luke 7:46](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Luke%207:46&version=AMP) - Woman washes Jesus' feet with expensive oil.

Your already quite versed in the subject, so it doesn't appear you require much explanation -- and the verses you point out have a common denominator:

**Anything - person, object, idea, lifestyle --- that is put above devotion to God is an idol.**

**Compare:**

[Genesis 25:34](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis%2025:34&version=AMP) - Esau trades birthright for bowl of stew.

[Luke 14:18](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Luke%2014:18&version=AMP) - Man finds excuse not to follow Christ, goes back to his newly purchased field.

[Philippians 3:19](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Philippians%203:19) - Self indulgent people idolize their own bellies/flesh.

EDIT: And as the verses you cite mention, bowing down to idols, making a likeness of anything to be revered -- also idolatry.

### Put simply:  **Worship the creator. Not the creation.**

On that note, I love Linux *way* more than Windows!

Comment: What if the actual definition of worship to God is (respecting creation more then the Creator) and where is the line between "Hey I can clean that counter, That counter is clean, That counter is so clean, I keep the cleanest counter around, Hey can't you see that I have cleaned this counter!". See the attitude ranges pointing at the object. So the question is that attitude in relation to "That counter is so clean". It is after the true statement yet before the boast. Yet this shows respect that it is clean. The direction of that respect is it truly at God? Sorry, that I trouble over this.

Comment: So you worship [Linus Torvalds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linus_Torvalds) but not Linux OS? :)